# How to grant "select" permission on public synonym "SHC.ABC" of table "SHC.ABC"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I created table called "SCH.ABC" and created PUBLIC synonym "SCH.ABC" now I want to  Grant "select" permission to schema "SCH1"  on synonym "ABC" . How can i do that please help resolving this.

I am creating synanym as same name of table, while granting permission we will not specify object type whether it is a table or a synonym.
If given, grant select on ABC to sch1; then which object type will get granted synonym or table ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I am creating synanym as same name of table, while granting permission we will not specify object type whether it is a table or synonym.
If give grant select on ABC to sch1; then which object type will get grant synonym or table ?

Answer (score 0):

*You already created a public synonym called `abc`, and you can grant selecting to a particular schema as*

`grant select on abc to sch1;`

*where you do not need to qualify with schema name as `sch.abc` by connecting to `sys` or `system` schemas.*

*or you can grant to all schemas as*

`grant select on abc to public;`

*and you don't need to qualify the public synonym `abc` with the schema name. Use*

`select * from abc;`

*in every schema in the database.*

Comment: Hi Barbaros , Thank you very much for your interest to answering it. I just now found that, in that case synonym only will get precedence of grant. I tested by drop synonym in my home Schema and tried accessing it in another schema it was giving error and i again created synonym after that it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your interest to answering it. I just now found that, in that case synonym only will get precedence of grant. I tested by drop synonym in my home Schema and tried accessing it in another schema it was giving error and i again created synonym after that it was working fine.